# Stay Connected when Internet is Back

Tags: codenameone

I have the following scenario using codename one:

1. I open a websocket connection to the server to receive incoming messages
2. I navigate through the app to perform other functionalities
3. I lose my internet connection so my websocket object is now NULL
4. How to **automatically** bind (reestablish) my websocket object (Connection) to the server again when the internet is back??

Appreciate your help a lot.

Regards,
Salah.

Comment: The websocket API's includes callbacks for error/close etc. You can use these callbacks to retry automatically on error.

Comment: Dear Shai, error call back will only be called when network is not available. Is it possible for you to add to this API a method to be called by the framework when network connection is back???

Comment: There is no callback for that natively. Developers poll when there is a disconnection and that gives you more control. Notice you can use the connectivity cn1lib to check if there is an internet connection